# Detect a change in the number of files or folders

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

The following script is supposed to check if the number of files and folders has changed since the last time the batch-file was run. If so, it prints a message and updates the counts.

Unfortunately it doesn't quite work. I think I have a problem with the `if` statements in my string comparisons.

Does anyone know how I can get the script to work?

```
@echo off

::Check number of dir's and files in last run    
set /p filecounta=<"countfile.log"
set /p dircounta=<"countdir.log"

::Check number number of dir's and files currently
for /f %%A in ('dir /a-d-s-h /b ^| find /v /c ""') do set filecountb=%%A
for /d %%G in (*) do set /a dircountb=dircountb+1

::Compares the number of counts in the past with the present
if not "%filecountb%"=="%filecounta%" goto :news
if not "%dircountb%"=="%dircounta%" goto :news

CALL :save
echo no news
pause
exit

:news
CALL :save
echo news
pause
exit

:: Subs

:: Put number of dir and files in log file
:save
echo %filecountb% >"countfile.log"
echo %dircountb% >"countdir.log"
GOTO:EOF
```

---

**Edit:**

After @Rik's suggestion I tried removing the space before `>` in
`echo %filecountb%>"countfile.log"` and `echo %dircountb%>"countdir.log"` but that didn't work in my OS. The solution was adding a `TRIM`-function to remove the spaces after reading them from the log-files.

```
::Check number of dir's and files in last run    
set /p filecounta=<"countfile.log"
set /p dircounta=<"countdir.log"
CALL :TRIM %filecounta% filecounta
CALL :TRIM %dircounta% dircounta

.
.
.

:TRIM
SET %2=%1
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place an echo before the if statements you'll see where the error is:

```
echo if NOT "%filecountb%" == "%filecounta%" goto :news
echo if NOT "%dircountb%" == "%dircounta%" goto :news
if NOT "%filecountb%" == "%filecounta%" goto :news
if NOT "%dircountb%" == "%dircounta%" goto :news
```

This is the result i got with the echo:

```
if NOT "10" == "10 " goto :news
if NOT "22" == "22 " goto :news
news
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Your `a`-results **have spaces behind them** (the ones you read from the log-files).

If you change your save routine to echo the variable **without** the space before `>` then it will work:

```
:save
echo %filecountb%>"countfile.log"
echo %dircountb%>"countdir.log"
```

Result:

```
if NOT "10" == "10" goto :news
if NOT "22" == "22" goto :news
no news
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: edited 1 post with solution

Comment: @RuiBranco Mmm, weird that removing the space before `>` didn't work for you (for me it does, under Windows 7). You **do** need to run it twice before you can see the effect because your existing `.log`s still had spaces in it. But your `TRIM`-function will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Try NEQ rather than NOT and ==

see: http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: The essential part I was attempting to pick out was to try NEQ rather than ==

Comment: Ah - sorry, my mistake.

Comment: No problem... My answer was admittedly too brief and I think Rik has nailed it anyway :/